# Maven project for both WAR and standalone server/client

Tags: java, maven

I have a POM-based Java project. It contains a number of servlets for deployment in a WAR. However, in addition to this, I also have classes that launch the application as a standalone using embedded servlet and database environments (for a turnkey development environment). Additionally, there is also a command-line client for the application.

I would like to have the ability to build the project into both the WAR and two separate executable JARS (one server, one client). I'm not concerned about the JARs/WAR containing some unnecessary code or deps- I just want all 3 to work.

What's the "correct" way to do this with Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple projects is the way to do this. Put the common code in the first project along with the standalone support. Then make a second with war packaging that depends on the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to do this. Assembly plugin can package `zip` or `tar.gz` archive for you. It's a perfect distribution format for standalone applications. When you configure assembly plugin you could link it to `package` phase, so application will be packaged in two formats: `war` and `zip`.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>assembly</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```